# prevent JTextArea's background image from stretching when getting scrolled down

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea with a background image that basically displays some output. The problem is when the output is appended and the JTextArea starts getting "auto-scrolled" down, the background image is getting stretched down as well... Is there any way to prevent that ?

To paint the image my JTextArea is overriding paintComponent as below :

```
public void paintComponent(final Graphics g)
{
    try {
        g.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(),0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then for the scrollpane :

```
DefaultCaret caret3 = (DefaultCaret)jTextArea2.getCaret();
caret3.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
jScrollPane5.setViewportView(jTextArea2);
new SmartScroller(jScrollPane5);
```

(SmartScroller class taken from here to achieve smart scrolling 
https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/smart-scrolling/ )

Any suggestions ?
Let me know if any further code needs to be posted.

Comment: Is there a way to put a jpanel with a layout manager between the jscrollpane and the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should display image depended on the visible rectangle. Something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle rect = getVisibleRect();
        g.drawImage(image.getImage(), rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, this);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
```